# How to send POST body when creating a python Zeep client

Tags: python, python-3.x, zeep

The API I am working with requires that I add a POST body when requesting the wsdl client. I'm using Zeep so it will look like this:

```
  client = Client(wsdl=url, settings=s)
```

How would I add a post body at this point?  I checked the settings documentation and it doesn't include a way for me to that. Is there an alternative way?

If that's not possible by the library, is it possible for me to make the request using the standard python request library and use the Zeep client to process the response?

**UPDATE**

Here is a sample payload I need to include. Unfortunately, I can't shared the exact URL I using.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:int="http://acme.com/integration/">
            <soap:Header>
                            <int:AcmeNetOptions>
                                            <int:ImposeConcurrencyId>true</int:ImposeConcurrencyId>
                                            <int:UpdateLastModified>true</int:UpdateLastModified>
                                            <int:CanDeleteMissingEntity>true</int:CanDeleteMissingEntity>
                                            <int:LockOnDataRetrieval>Default</int:LockOnDataRetrieval>
                            </int:AcmeNetOptions>
            </soap:Header>
            <soap:Body>
                            <int:Login>
                                            <int:username>username</int:username>
                                            <int:password>password</int:password>
                                            <int:companyname>company</int:companyname>
                            </int:Login>
            </soap:Body>
```

Comment: What do you want to post in xml? Authentication measures? It can be set with wsse param. Also to answer second question, yes you can download the wsdl via requests and save it to a file then zeep can process it.

Comment: @Tarique. Do I need to save the response into a file? I cannot create the zeep client in memory?

Comment: if you give us more info like what wsdl are you using and what xml you need to post with it? also if you tried with soapui then let us know the exact xml for request. then please add it to question then we would be able to help you in better ways. To answer your question, yes you need to save the wsdl to disk. then you can pass the file to zeep. I havn't tried to pass in memory wsdl to zeep.

Comment: @Tarique I updated the OP to give an example of a payload I am trying to include when creating the client. To answer your first comment, yes, these are authentication measures.

Comment: Here's the example usage of http post binding: https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/blob/master/examples/km_to_miles.py -- does this look like what you need?

Comment: @PavelVergeev I don't follow. How did your example create a Client while passing a POST body? That code, looks to me, created the client without passing a post pody.

Comment: Hi, I checked source code of `zeep`. Unfortunately it's not possible in zeep to send a body while creating a client. You need to use `requests` to download the wsdl and then use it.